# mysql not connect from remove pc installed on Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I have just created one instance on Amazon EC2 for CentOs, and installed mysql on it with root user (password is blank). Then I had created another user for me to connect this instance from remote pc (my local pc). for that I had run following command on terminal one by one.

```
CREATE USER 'demouser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'demopassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'demouser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I wrote following line in /etc/my.cnf under [mysqld] section

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Then restarted mysql with following command

```
sudo /sbin/service mysqld restart
```

Still, It is not allowed to connect that instance from my local pc. I don't understand what is the problem? I had checked and confirmed that rules on Amazon Security Groups are set properly. (e.g. port 3306 & 22 set to 0.0.0.0 ip address, means any ip address can connect using both ports).

Can someone saw me the mistake of mine?

Answer (score 0):

Slowed 
I ran following command to update ipaddress in centos terminal;

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

and It's getting connected... !!!!